# How to reduce CPU usage by progress bar for a currently playing track when there are lots of tracks in playlist?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a music player. I want to show a progress bar right in a playlist for a song which is currently playing. No any problems, if there are few tracks in playlist, but if there are more than 100 tracks - everything starts to work really slowly and CPU usage rises from ~5-10% up to 30%. There is a UI button, which can remove selected track, so if I remove from playlist the currently playing track (read it as if I remove progress animation, because the track continues playing) the CPU usage drops to ~5-10%.

I use `vue-bootstrap` in my app, but I also tried raw `Bootstrap 4` and even custom css, nothing changes - still high usage of CPU in case of big playlist.

Also if I remove `b-progress` tag (or `div` in case of raw Bootstrap and custom solution) from a code, everything is ok.

In `data\playlist\tracks` there are two examples of tracks just to show the data structure.

I think the problem somehow has a relation to vue's reactivity (too many tracks to watch?) or maybe relates somehow to a loop itself.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a possible workaround?

```
<template>
  <b-container>

    <youtube :video-id="currentTrack['trackId']" ref="youtube"></youtube>

    <div v-for="(trackObj, index) in playlist.tracks" :key="trackObj.trackId">
      <b-card no-body @click="playTrack(trackObj)">

      // THIS BLOCK IS CPU HUNGRY
      <b-progress v-if="currentTrack['trackId'] === trackObj['trackId']">
        <b-progress-bar
          :value="currentTrackTime" 
          :max="currentTrack['totalTrackDuration']">
        </b-progress-bar>
        {{ index + 1 }}. {{ trackObj.trackTitle }}
      </b-progress>

      <div v-else>
        {{ index + 1 }}. {{ trackObj.trackTitle }}
      </div>

      </b-card>
    </div>

  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentTrackTime: 0,

      currentTrack: {
        trackId: '1',
        trackTitle: 'Snowmine - Let me in',
        totalTrackDuration: 220,
      },

      playlist: {
        playlistName: 'SomeName',
        tracks: [
          {
            trackId: '1',
            trackTitle: 'Snowmine - Let me in',
            totalTrackDuration: 220,
          },
          {
            trackId: '2',
            trackTitle: 'Moby - Porcelain',
            totalTrackDuration: 245,
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    playTrack (trackObj) {
      this.currentTrack = trackObj
      this.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo()
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    let self = this

    setInterval(function () {
        self.$refs.youtube.player.getCurrentTime().then(data => { self.currentTrackTime = data })
    }, 1000)
  }
}
</script>
```

Youtube component taken from [here](https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-youtube)

Comment: Is there some code that updates `currentTrackTime`?

Comment: @RoyJ, sorry, forgot about it. Added.

Comment: A couple things to try: change the interval to 5000 and see if it makes much difference. Put a console message in the `then` so you can see if it's really just happening once a second (or once every 5 seconds if you change the interval).

Comment: Where is the `ref="youtube"` element?

Comment: @RoyJ, this is the problem :) So silly. CPU usage came back to 5% with a spikes every 5 seconds to 11%. It seems that I need to google for an alternative of `setInterval`. You can post this solution.

Comment: How / where do you assign `currentTrack`? Also, shouldn't it be `:max="currentTrack.totalTrackDuration"`?

Comment: @Phil, you are correct about `:max="currentTrack.totalTrackDuration"`. I tried to show as minimal code as possible, so this is the reason why `ref="youtube"` and assigning of `currentTrack` not included. As `Roy J`s suggestion is correct, the problem is found. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: I don't think it's solved. Your page should be able to handle 1s intervals just as well as 5s ones.

Comment: @Phil, I added requested pieces of code